# Tag clouds / topic clouds for Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, tags, stack-exchange

I noticed [this wonderful tag cloud](https://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-made-a-concept-map-or-a-mindmap-of-all-known-mathematical-knowledge) describing the interconnecton of topics on Math Stack Exchange. I recall seeing tools like this on the internet. I don't recall if Stack Exchange itself generates such charts.

[image]

[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) certainly did not turn up anything graphical.

---

I recall there being an online service which generated such charts, but I don't remember if it was directly affiliated with Stack Exchange or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this originated with some [code](https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki) by Piotr Migdal [several years ago](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6479/170257) on Math Stack Exchange (with at least [one update](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19617/170257)). The project was independent of Stack Exchange, and eventually was applied to other sites (e.g. [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6525/56299)), becoming the fully interactive [Tag Overflow](https://github.com/stared/tagoverflow#tagoverflow), letting you generate your own graphs for various sites. There are also [even bigger maps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157976/274942).

It gets data via the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Comment: not exactly life-changing but extremely informative nonetheless.  This was exactly the one. Thanks.