# Stack Exchange Bacon

Tags: discussion, migration

I am interested in the [Bacon Number](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon_number#:%7E:text=The%20Bacon%20number%20of%20an,concept%20to%20the%20movie%20industry.) for Stack Exchange sites, based on migrated questions.

For example, I suspect that there will be a lot of migration between Stack Overflow and SuperUser, or Pets and Biology; but perhaps not so much between WorldBuilding and CodeReview. It would be interesting to see a graph or chart of migrations over the past (say) year, which could be used to build "degrees of separation" between the sites.

It would also be interesting to see if that matched up with the numbers of users who are members of those pairs of sites.

Hopefully this request is on-topic here

Comment: How are you defining the Bacon Number in this case? Is it between a post on site a and a post on site b in which case how do you step from one to another? Posts by the same user on a different site? Then answers by a different user or what?

Comment: Related: [Map of all Stack Exchange sites (except the three biggest)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157976/278659)

Comment: I was imagining that only some of the sites would have posts that are migrated from one to another (e.g. you would never get a post migrated from pets to codereview). So to get to codereview from pets you might have a post that's migrated to Biology. Then there might be another post that was migrated from Bio to Philosophy; and so on and so on until you reached CodeReview

Comment: I'm not sure if this would tell you anything useful or not, but I thought it might be interesting anyway...

Comment: I expected something completely different when I read the title.

Comment: I suspect I might have an actual bacon number . I worked in a vfx studio for a bit

Comment: @RobertColumbia I eggspected something completely different when I read the title.

Comment: [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1266073/migration-stats-networkwide?fromDate=2020-01-01) is a list of all migrations, grouped by origin and destination.

Comment: That's an interesting query Glorfindel - I didn't realise we migrate to 18 sites from Sec.SE